# Using function parameters within vuejs data object properties

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

This is a method that I wrote for a Nuxt app that works just fine but as with many of my methods that do simple things like this, the code is verbose and I'd like for it to be more condensed.

How can I rewrite this so that `num` is placed in the proper places and repeating the logic is not required to accommodate different `num`s?

```
removeDependent(num) {
  if (num === 1) {
    this.dependent1 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[1].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[1].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[1].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[1].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[1].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[1].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[1].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 2) {
    this.dependent2 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[2].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[2].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[2].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[2].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[2].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[2].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[2].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 3) {
    this.dependent3 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[3].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[3].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[3].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[3].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[3].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[3].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[3].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 4) {
    this.dependent4 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[4].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[4].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[4].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[4].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[4].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[4].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[4].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 5) {
    this.dependent5 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[5].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[5].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[5].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[5].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[5].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[5].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[5].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 6) {
    this.dependent6 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[6].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[6].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[6].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[6].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[6].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[6].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[6].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 7) {
    this.dependent7 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[7].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[7].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[7].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[7].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[7].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[7].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[7].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 8) {
    this.dependent8 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[8].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[8].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[8].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[8].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[8].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[8].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[8].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 9) {
    this.dependent9 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[9].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[9].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[9].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[9].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[9].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[9].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[9].ssn = "";
  } else if (num === 10) {
    this.dependent10 = false;
    this.employee.dependents[10].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[10].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[10].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[10].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[10].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[10].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[10].ssn = "";
  }
  return null;
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `num` parameter as index :

```
removeDependent(num) {
 if(num){
    this[`dependent${num}`] = false;
    this.employee.dependents[num].type = "";
    this.employee.dependents[num].products = [];
    this.employee.dependents[num].firstName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[num].lastName = "";
    this.employee.dependents[num].dob = "";
    this.employee.dependents[num].gender = "";
    this.employee.dependents[num].ssn = "";
  } else return null;
}
```

Comment: Could I use: 
`this[dependent${num}] = false; `
With the required back ticks of course.  Can't show those in the comments

Comment: Answering my own question here... You can use a String Literal in the first statement.  Thanks very much for the help @Boussadjra Brahim

Answer (score 1):

Some improvement from another answer, code can be shorten using best practices. Also return null is the default so no need to use it.

```
removeDependent(num) {
 if(num) {
    this[`dependent${num}`] = false;
    this.employee.dependents[num] = {
      type: "",
      products: [],
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      dob: "",
      ssn: ""
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Paridhi.  I like the neatness of this.  Definite improvement.